# How can I stockpile Harming II arrows?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

What is the most effective way to farm Harming II arrows in Minecraft bedrock edition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're best off with a witch farm, and a brown mushroom farm, and a nether wart farm. A general mob farm (with player killing the mobs) will be also helpful.

Witches will provide you with unlimited supply of:

- spider eyes
- glowstone
- empty bottles
- sugar
- sticks, if you choose to craft the arrows, or trade with a fletcher.

That's 4 of the needed components, and one useful materials. You'll also need Nether Wart, and brown mushrooms, and a couple blaze rods, and your potion situation is solved. Brown mushrooms are a bit of a problem - they grow very slowly and aren't easily found in large amounts, so an automatic farm for them is going to be big. Although you can grow them into giant mushrooms and these will drop more when harvested (with a non-silktouch axe) - for this you need bonemeal.

A general mob farm will provide you with spider eyes (witches don't drop that many, and you need 2 per batch), arrows, and bones -> bonemeal. Alternatively, you can trade sticks for arrows (32 sticks - 1 emerald - 16 arrows)  with a fletcher.

If you decide to craft your own arrows, you'll also need a chicken farm (an automatic chicken cooker is a good source of these - and food), and visit gravel mountains with a Fortune III shovel (or just have patience placing and breaking gravel over and over).

After that, it's easy. Fill bottles with water, brew Awkward potion with nether wart, Poison with regular spider eye, craft sugar, spider eye and brown mushroom into fermented spider eye, brew the poison with that, and then improve with glowstone. Pour 3 potions into a cauldron and use a stack of arrows on it to convert them to tipped. And enjoy the surplus of gunpowder and redstone from the witch farm.

Comment: SF yes thanks, but... that's the most efficient but is it the most simple?

Comment: @Blue_glue Depends on how many arrows you want. If you want one stack, of course not. If you want a constant production, it's definitely more simple than caving for spiders and skeletons.

Comment: ok, but does a witch farm work in bedrock?

Comment: @Blue_glue apparently there are working designs on Youtube, I don't play enough BE to verify them. You're in this luxurious situation that you don't need Dragon Breath anyway.

Comment: yeah I guess you're right

Comment: @Blue_glue the other, less efficient way to make a harming potion is to farm melons and zombie piglins to make glistering melons, which make potions of healing; but then you still need to have a multi-farm to make fermented spider eyes, instead of using spider eyes from that same farm to make poison potions. it also depends on what resources you have, so whichever way works. i suggest SF.'s method

Answer (score 1):

i believe you can get a cauldron and put a potion in it, then you can dip arrows

Comment: true, but it is only possible in bedrock edition (yes, i know the OP tagged it that, i'm just letting everyone else know that the cauldron method doesn't work in other versions)

Comment: yes, that is the most effective way to make them(because you get 16 per potion instead of 8 per potion(crafting)), but I meant to farm the ingredients to make them

Comment: @PvParkour thats fine

Comment: @Blue_glue i wish there was a version of minecraft that had all the best things about each version, like how you can do the cauldron dipping, and actually being able to put potions in cauldrons. I'm not sure what the best redstone mechanics would be though. and of course the version would be updated normally, and not stuck in 1.13 like Xbox is